# mvc5 razor check session value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, razor

I am trying to get session value in mvc5 razor as below

```
@{var cnt=Session["count"].ToString();}
@if (cnt == "0" || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cnt))
```

This results in an error if there is no value for session.  How should this be checked

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I'd really avoid checking session variables in your view

Comment: how do you do it  when you have to show an alternative html or  view if session is null in a shopping cart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply check if its null

```
@if (Session["count"] != null) { 
    //Do what you want 
}
```